# Javascript: display all user info (ie. the navigator object) for debugging

Tags: javascript

I was about to write a script to dump out everything in navigator (excluding window) to help with debugging user issues (instead of asking the user what browser/operating system they're running, I'd like to point them to a page that dumps out everything interesting), and it occurred to me this has probably been done a million times before.

Do you know of a good cross browser, light script for dumping out all interesting user info? Bonus points if it has a clever way of getting the data to me (ie. avoids cut-paste-email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great website, I always point people to this site when they need help:

http://www.supportdetails.com/

Plus, it has built-in system for sending emails. If you want to make your own but base it off of their code, most of the code for this is:

```
 // Screen Res
 if (self.screen)
 {
  S_RESOLUTION = screen.width + ' x ' + screen.height;
  S_COLOR_DEPTH = screen.colorDepth + ' bit';
 }
 else if (self.java)
 {
  var javaobj = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  var screenobj = javaobj.getScreenSize();

  S_RESOLUTION = screenobj.width + ' x ' + screenobj.height;

  if (self.screen)
   S_COLOR_DEPTH = screen.colorDepth + ' bit'; ;
 }

 // Browser size
 var bsw = '';
 var bsh = '';

 if (window.innerWidth)
 {
  bsw = window.innerWidth;
  bsh = window.innerHeight;
 }
 else if (document.documentElement)
 {
  bsw = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  bsh = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 }
 else if (document.body)
 {
  bsw = document.body.clientWidth;
  bsh = document.body.clientHeight;
 }
 if (bsw != '' && bsh != '')
 {
  S_BROWSER_SIZE = bsw + ' x ' + bsh;
 }

 // Browser Type
 if (S_USE_CLIENT_FOR_BROWSER == "1")
 {
  var browser = $.browser.name + " " + $.browser.version;
  S_BROWSER_TYPE = browser;

  S_BROWSER_TYPE = S_BROWSER_TYPE.replace("msie", "Internet Explorer");

  if (S_BROWSER_TYPE.length > 0)
  {
   S_BROWSER_TYPE = S_BROWSER_TYPE.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + S_BROWSER_TYPE.substring(1, S_BROWSER_TYPE.length);
  }

  S_BROWSER_VERSION = "";
 }
```

Comment: That's quite nice, thanks. I'd still like to see code as well so we can host it on our server and integrate it with our own pieces of user info.

Comment: You can just look at the source code of there site, and all the code is in there (it's not obsfucated). Most of it is here: http://www.supportdetails.com/includes/js/support-details.js?v12 (look under the getBrowserDetails function)